# CLI gcloud - The following signatures could not be verified because their public key is not available

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to install the gcloud CLI on my Linux system with Elementary OS 6.1 (based on Ubuntu 20.04) following the steps of the official page: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install?hl=en . Apparently everything was ok with the installation, but now when I run sudo apt get-update I get an error with the repository:

```
Err:21 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
  The following signatures could not be verified because their public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05

W: GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease: The following signatures could not be verified because their public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
E: The repository “https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease” is not signed.
```

How can I solve this? I've tried with

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes,could you please have a look at this [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and accordingly proceed.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestions?  and your issue is resolved?

Comment: Have you tried my solution

Answer (score 0):

As per this GCP official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/known-issues#keyexpired)

This is a known issue. Without manually upgrading the key, I believe the reproducer would be using apt update in an already-existing installation.

The main issue which affected Ubuntu operating on Google Cloud Platform was changing keys with GCP , so that the Public key needs to be updated.

To resolve your issue execute the following command to acquire the most recent key:

```
curl -O https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg \
    && apt-key add apt-key.gpg
```

Or

```
curl -f https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg \
    | sudo apt-key add -
```

If the curl is not working try below command

```
wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg \
    && apt-key add apt-key.gpg
```

Still If you are facing an error you might have to run below command  instead or update the location of the key file.

```
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
```

If you use above any command you will get the key like below

> ------BEGIN PGP public Block----
>
> Key information
>
> ------END PGP public Block----

Refer this [Gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes/release/issues/2862) for more information